# sqlalchemy: is rollback required on every commit?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy for my web app. I've seen a lot of code like this:

```
try:
   session.commit()
except:
   session.rollback()
```

I'm wondering if it's necessary for each `commit()` operation. If it is, then why isn't it part of the `commit()` operation? How to decide when to `rollback()` and when not?

Comment: If you find yourself writing this kind of boilerplate a lot, break it out into a function. PS you shouldn't do `except` but rather `except Exception:` since the bare `except` can catch things you generally wouldn't want to catch.

Answer (score 5):

When commit fails it just means that the transaction cannot complete without breaking some constraints. So in principle, instead of rolling back you could make some updates and try committing again.

In practice, such error recovery logic is non-trivial to reason about, so most people just roll back (undo any changes made for the transaction) to keep data in consistent state, and communicate the problem to the user.

Comment: thanks. following on question: how do I make the `commit()` call to fail for testing the rollback?

Comment: You would want to violate some constraint. Probably the easiest thing to do is to change the primary key of the modified row to either become non-unique (for INSERT) or non-existent (for UPDATE).