# SQLAlchemy session commit exception handing with rollback

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to figure out the preferred way to manage session if exceptiion occurs while doing operation or committing the session. But a few examples in the document confuses me a little bit.

The doc says to [frame out a commit/rollback block](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#framing-out-a-begin-commit-rollback-block), you can do something like this:

```py
# verbose version of what a context manager will do
with Session(engine) as session:
    session.begin()
    try:
        session.add(some_object)
        session.add(some_other_object)
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    else:
        session.commit()
```

While [this example](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_transaction.html#explicit-begin) includes the `commit()` call in the `try` block:

```py
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
session.begin()
try:
    item1 = session.query(Item).get(1)
    item2 = session.query(Item).get(2)
    item1.foo = 'bar'
    item2.bar = 'foo'
    session.commit()
except:
    session.rollback()
    raise
```

I wonder:

1. what's the difference between these two patterns?
2. which is the preferred way for managing transaction?
3. The doc says both example above can be succinctly illustrated with `session.begin()` context manager, so does it handle the exception occurs while `commit()` ?

Possible related answes:

Here is a [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52234206/11887333) that exludes `commit()` from the `try` block, but the explanation in the comments doesn't seem sufficient to me.
And this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36381511/11887333) mentions about why including `commit()` in `try` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both examples accomplish nearly the same thing. The transaction will be committed if there is no error, and rolled back if there is an error.

The difference is that if there is an exception *on the commit itself*, the second example will roll back. It's uncommon to get an exception on the commit, but it's possible.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the exception on the commit per se? Also am I supposed to rollback the session when commit throws an error?

Comment: Depending on the nature of the exception, there may be cases where you could retry the commit. You don't always have to rollback if you get an exception on the commit. So either form is correct in different circumstances.

Comment: So does the `begin()` context manager handles the commit exception as well? or it just propagates the error?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know for sure. In MySQL, errors on commit are rare. MySQL doesn't support deferred constraints like some other SQL databases do. In other databases, certain constraints (like unique) may be checked at commit. In MySQL, those constraints may only be checked on the insert/update/delete statement, so by the time you get to commit, it would take an extraordinary failure to cause an error.